# How to run regression with partially known coefficients? I.e. how use offset-function (Taylor rule model)

Tags: r, linear-regression, offset

I am trying to run a regression in the form of `Y = X1 (with known coefficient 1) + X2 (with known coefficient 1) + beta1 * X3 + beta2 * X4 + beta0` (as there may be other influences on `Y`)

(For people who are familiar with Econ and the Taylor Rule Model, `Y` is the nominal interest rate, while `X1` is the inflation rate, `X2` is the neutral real interest rate, `X3` is inflation gap and `X4` is output gap.)

My question now is how to run this in R. I believe I should use the offset function, although I don't know how to code it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Y = X1 (with known coefficient 1) + X2 (with known coefficient 1) + 
    beta1 * X3 + beta2 * X4 + beta0
```

Assuming that by "known coefficient 1" you mean "the coefficient is known to be equal to 1" (I'm not an economist), this would correspond to

```r
y ~ x3 + x4 + offset(x1 + x2)
```

(If you had coefficients !=1 you could include them in the offset, e.g. `offset(2.1*x1 + 3.5*x2)`.) If you are using a linear model this can be done even more simply (although less interpretably) via

```r
y - x1 - x2 ~ x3 + x4
```

(offsets are really only *necessary* for generalized linear models, where subtracting from the LHS doesn't work)

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick answer!
1) I tried the first method but unfortunately it didn't seem to work. The fitted values are not equal to the values I get when I manually calculate them using the resulting coefficients from the regression, i.e. the fitted values are equal those that I get if I do not have x1 and x2 in the regression at all. I'm assuming the offset function didn't work in this case?


2) Using the second method, the fitted values that I get are for the whole term (y - x1 - x2)  right? So if I want what y is, I have to subtract x1 and x2 from the fitted values?

Comment: if you want why you would *add* x1 and x2 to the fitted values.  Unclear why the offset wouldn't work; do you have a [mcve]?